# Is it ok to wipe down hvac intern aka with white vinegar/bleach?

Tags: hvac, cleaning

I am going to be cleaning inside the scuttle panel and taking the my HVAC system apart to clean inside it.

Is it ok to mix white vinegar or bleach/Dettol(similar to Lysol cleaner marketed in the USA) mixed with some water or more these damage surfaces, rubber, parts etc.?

If not, what should I use instead?  Preferably something which will leave no chemical residues or it will dissipate afterwards as I don’t want to breathe the fumes in later.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should **absolutely not mix vinegar and bleach** as the combination creates **chlorine gas**, which is **hazardous**. Chlorine gas is used as a chemical warfare agent, you don't want to be creating it.

What cleaner to use depends on what you need to clean, you won't necessarily know until you open it up. You'll probably want something that can remove grease and oil, so kitchen cleaners will probably do fine. Rinse it afterwards with clean water.

Comment: Sorry gdd I meant one or the other.  Vinegar any itself, or bleach could be considered a kitchen cleaner?